# How stop after correct answer (PYTHON)

Tags: python

When player1 write correct answer scrypt don't write message about winning & give a chance for next player. How fix it?(

```
while attempt != number:
    count += 1
    if count > max_count:
        print(f'All players have used {count-1} attempts and are lose')
        break
    print(f'Attempt No. {count}')
    for player in players:
        print(f'Attemp of player {player}')
        attempt = int(input('Enter your number: '))
        if attempt > number:
            print('No. Get smaller')
        elif attempt < number:
            print('No. Get bigger')
else:
    print('Great! You WIN')
```

Comment: problems with offset/tabulation. Just place else:   print('Great! You WIN') under elif

Comment: Thanx! U help me)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `else` is not properly indented. It acts as an else for the `while` loop, that does a completely [different thing](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_while_else.asp).

What you need to do is to indent the else statement so it's at the same level as the `if` and the `elif`. Python doesn't work with blocks as other languages do, using brackets to mark the limits. Instead, it uses indentation, which forces you to indent everything properly. The code would result as:

```py
while attempt != number:
    count += 1
    if count > max_count:
        print(f'All players have used {count-1} attempts and are lose')
        break
    print(f'Attempt No. {count}')
    for player in players:
        print(f'Attemp of player {player}')
        attempt = int(input('Enter your number: '))
        if attempt > number:
            print('No. Get smaller')
        elif attempt < number:
            print('No. Get bigger')
        else:
            print('Great! You WIN')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a break statement to stop the loop when answered correctly as follows:

```
while attempt != number:
    count += 1
    if count > max_count:
        print(f'All players have used {count-1} attempts and are lose')
        break
    print(f'Attempt No. {count}')
    for player in players:
        print(f'Attemp of player {player}')
        attempt = int(input('Enter your number: '))
        if attempt > number:
            print('No. Get smaller')
        elif attempt < number:
            print('No. Get bigger')
        else:
            break
else:
    print('Great! You WIN')
```

Or you can just print the winning text and continue with the loop.

```
while attempt != number:
    count += 1
    if count > max_count:
        print(f'All players have used {count-1} attempts and are lose')
        break
    print(f'Attempt No. {count}')
    for player in players:
        print(f'Attemp of player {player}')
        attempt = int(input('Enter your number: '))
        if attempt > number:
            print('No. Get smaller')
        elif attempt < number:
            print('No. Get bigger')
        else:
            print('Great! You WIN')
```